# What directory should packages/modules be written to?

Tags: directory, enthought, solver, canopy, glpk

When installing GLPK from (from https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk), I get the following error:

libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libglpk.36.dylib /usr/local/lib/libglpk.36.dylib
install: /usr/local/lib/libglpk.36.dylib: Permission denied

I have tried installing to other locations successfully, but python does not find the package.  I would like to run.  Note:  I am using Enghought Canopy to run Python on Mac OS X version 10.9.4.

Answer (score 0):

You don't install a non-python package into Python. You install it on your system (not a python issue, maybe someone else will have a suggestion), and then install a python package which "wraps" it -- provides access to it in python. If you have already successfully installed GLPK, then you should simply be able to open a Canopy Terminal window from the Canopy Tools menu, and type:

```
pip install glpk
```

EDIT: It looks like this is the best place for examples of using it: http://www.tfinley.net/software/pyglpk/examples.html